# Одномерные массивы в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Задание заключается в следующем: **Найти сумму элементов массива A={a[i]} удовлетворяет условию с <= a[i] <= d**

1)Как в ассемблере можно объявить массив?

2)Каким образом можно сравнивать каждый элемент массива с одним и тем же числом?(В моем случае `a[i]` с `c` и `d`)

*P.S. Пишу на dos*

Comment: 1 - в целом зависит от конкретного ассемблера: в tasm, fasm, masm одним способом, в nasm другим, в gas третьим. Поэтому нужно указывать используемый ассемблер в вопросе. 2 - циклом пройти по массиву, сравнивая каждый элемент с одним и тем же числом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.MODEL Large,C
    .data
    Extrn C cccS:word,dddS:word,mass:word,nnnS:word,result:word;
    .code
    Public  Lab3S
    a EQU mass[bx]
Lab3s   proc    far


    xor bx,bx

    mov cx,nnnS
    loop1:
    mov ax,a
    cwd
    cmp ax,cccS
    JE equal
    JG great
    JL less

    equal:
    add result,ax
    jmp jump

    less:
    jmp jump

    great:
    cmp ax,dddS
    JE equal2
    JL less2
    JG great2
    equal2:
    add result,ax
    jmp jump
    less2:
    add result,ax
    jmp jump
    great2:
    jmp jump

    jump:
    inc bx
    inc bx
    loop loop1

    ret
Lab3S   endp
    end
```

Comment: а что из всего этого массив ?

Comment: @MaximLensky,  `a EQU mass[bx]`, т.е. a - алиас для `mass[bx]` (так себе решение, только усложняет понимание кода), сам массив похоже где-то в отдельном файле, раз он в extrn объявлен.